# How to get multiple data from java using JDBC

Tags: spring, jdbc

how to use multiple queries in java Maven Spring using jdbc here DB confection predefined ans get out put from DB as '5' i need other fields data like name, group, status on same table on a single call.

```
 public String testMysqlCall() throws Exception {
            try {
                return gopuJdbcTemplate.query("select id from gopu limit 5", new IdMapper());
            } catch( Exception e) {
                throw e;
            }
        }

    private class IdMapper implements ResultSetExtractor<String> {
        public String extractData(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
            String toReturn=null;
            while(resultSet.next()) {
                toReturn = resultSet.getString("id");

            }
            return toReturn;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The SQL query you're executing in your code is the following:

> select id from gopu limit 5

Because it says "select **id** from" it will *only* return the **id** value in your results.

To return multiple columns, either explicitly declare them:

> select id, name, group, status from gopu limit 5

Or use a wildcard symbol to return **all** columns:

> select * from gopu limit 5

Comment: got this error  after adding select id, name  from gopu limit 5   


org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select id, name gopu limit 5]; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'id' in 'field list'

Comment: Are you sure the SQL query is `select id, name FROM gopu limit 5`? I'm asking because the query in the exception message doesn't mention the "from". It's hard to debug without actually seeing the code or the database :). Did you try it with the asterix (`*`) symbol to see if that works?

Comment: Ya same for both query asterix i think to fetch data need to pass it to an array